# Field (Test.title) is required but not initial, and has no default or generated value

Tags: keystonejs

I was wondering if someone knows why I get that error, my model

```
var Test = new keystone.List('Test', {
    autokey: { from: 'title', path: 'key', unique: true }
});

Test.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
```

All I did was change the values from the post example below

```
var Test = new keystone.List('Test', {
    autokey: { from: 'name', path: 'key', unique: true }
});

Test.add({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
```

I can;t understand why it works with name and not with title

Answer (score 1):

use map key inside option list

```
var Test = new keystone.List('Test', {
    map: { name: 'title' },
    autokey: { from: 'title', path: 'key', unique: true }
});
```

refs: http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#lists-options

> An object that maps fields to special list paths. Each path defaults
>   to its key if a field with that key is added. Mappable paths include
>   name - the field that contains the name of the item, for display in
>   the Admin UI